# query for date time correction

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have 3 columns of `varchar(max)` data-type; these columns contain dates (i.e `03/12/2004` -> in this format).

1. These columns contain some invalid dates i.e `30/02/2004` -> problem with February's month dates

   I used this query which gives invalid dates as 0 & valid dates 1, but I am unable to correct these dates after getting 0 & 1. Please give me the solution how to correct these. i.e `30/02/2003` to `01/03/2003`

   ```
   SET  DATEFORMAT dmy   
   SELECT Visit_Date, ISDATE(Visit_Date) as ValidDate
   FROM TABLE_NAME
   ```
2. After correcting these dates in 3 columns, how do I convert the column datatypes to `datetime` type? (remember record in each column is 2.5 million).

Comment: Do you have any dates like `03/15`2004`?  What I'm getting at is, are you sure the format is `DD/MM/YYYY`, as opposed to `MM/DD/YYYY`?  Good for moving to a proper date/time/timestamp type, though.

Comment: I m sure the format is DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure which are the wrong dates and what are the correct dates you can do a simple `UPDATE` like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET Visit_Date = IIF(Visit_Date = '30/02/2003', '01/03/2003', Visit_Date)
```

or in case you are not using `SQL Server 2012` the statement above looks like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET Visit_Date = CASE WHEN Visit_Date = '30/02/2003' THEN '01/03/2003' ELSE Visit_Date END
```

EDIT:

You can use the following statement to correct the dates:

```
CREATE TABLE DataSource 
(
  [Date] VARCHAR(128) 
)

INSERT INTO DataSource ([Date])
VALUES ('27/02/2003')
      ,('28/02/2003')
      ,('29/02/2003') 
      ,('30/02/2003')
      ,('31/02/2003')
      ,('32/02/2003')
      ,('33/02/2003')
      ,('34/02/2003')
      ,('35/02/2003')
      ,('36/02/2003')

SELECT COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DATE,[Date])
               ,DATEADD(DAY
                 ,CAST(SUBSTRING([Date],0,3) AS INT) - 1
                 ,DATEADD(MONTH
                          ,(SUBSTRING([Date],7,4) - 1900) * 12 + SUBSTRING([Date],4,2) - 1 
                          ,0)
                )
       )
FROM DataSource
```

Basically, it creat a new date using the year and the month from your date string. For exmaple, if the `Date` value is `29/02/2003` it will create a new date '2003-02-01'. After that it adds the days from the `Date` value to the new date using [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function and leave the SQL Server to calculated itself the new date.

The output from the above query is:

[image]

and here is a full working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ebc66/12)

Comment: thnx 4 ur reply....the thing is,,there are 2.5 million records(dates)in each column,,30/02/2003-> its one kind of wrong date,,I have just quoted here for better understanding...secondly i am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @usman_zufi Is this helpful? Or your situation is complex and you need an other tehnique to use?

Comment: Your solution is somehow specific..i checked most of the incorrect dates,all have the problem with february month,,.i want that if whether there is 29 or 30,,they all updated to next correct date while keeping the year of the date as it is,,.

Comment: @usman_zufi You can check the new technique, too. It is simply displaying how the things are working - you can esay implement it in an update statement.

Comment: 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.,,the query is given this error..

Comment: i tried the above given query,,it works fine on sample table and data but on actual data with record of 2.5 million it's giving error...visit_date(varchar(max)) is one of the column in my table,,so it is giving this error............Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/' to data type int.

Comment: this is my query...... SELECT 
 CASE 
 WHEN ISDATE(Visit_Date) = 1 THEN [Visit_Date]ELSE

DATEADD(DAY,CAST(SUBSTRING([Visit_Date],0,3)AS varchar ) - 1
, DATEADD(MONTH,(SUBSTRING([Visit_Date],7,4) - 1900) * 12 + SUBSTRING([Visit_Date],4,2) - 1 
 ,0)
 )
 END
FROM table_name

Comment: @usman_zufi The error is clear enough - `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/' to data type int.` and the only place where we are doing such conversion is here - `CAST(SUBSTRING([Date],0,3) AS INT) - 1`. I guess, there are some something wrong with the `[Date]` value - try to add 'LTRIM(RTRIM([Date]))' in order to clear trailing spaces.